# Is there an alternative to onNewToken if I don't want to implement a FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app only needs FCM notifications while the app is in the background. For this reason, I actually don't need a `FirebaseMessagingService`. I have only added it to my app to handle the `onNewToken` callback in case the token changes while the app is running:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ChatFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Inject
    lateinit var sessionManager: SessionManager

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        sessionManager.currentChatUser?.let {
            userRepository.persistCurrentFcmToken(it)
        }
    }
}
```

`persistCurrentFcmToken` lives in the repository:

**I also call this method when a user logs in**

```
fun persistCurrentFcmToken(user: ChatUser) {
    applicationScope.launch {
        val token = messaging.awaitToken() ?: return@launch

        val tokenList = user.fcmTokens?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()

        if (!tokenList.contains(token)) {
            tokenList.add(token)
            val userUpdate = user.copy(fcmTokens = tokenList)

            userCollection.document(user.uid!!).set(userUpdate)
        }
    } 
}
```

The FirebaseMessagingService feels a bit pointless since I don't need foreground notifications. Is there a way to get rid of it or is the `onNewToken` callback inevitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app doesn't have a `FirebaseMessagingService` and the token is changed while the user is not using the app, your server will send the messages to the old token, and the device won't receive them.

Creating a `FirebaseMessagingService` actually ensures that your application code gets notified of token changes when the app is not actively being used. There is no way to get such a notification without a `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is it common to have a `FirebaseMessagingService` that only implements `onNewToken` and nothing else? For an app that only needs notifications while the app is in the background.

Comment: The main reason to have a `FirebaseMessagingService` is to detect token changes, so it's quite common that `onNewToken` is the only method implemented in there.